# how to only show one rows with the same value through joined tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have the id of an artist and I'd like to know all the albums released by this artist.

**MySQL Structure**

[image: MySQL structure]

**Example Mysql Query**

```
SELECT album_name 
FROM albums AS a, 
     tracks AS t, 
     produced AS p 
WHERE p.produced_track = t.track_id 
  AND t.track_album = a.album_id 
AND p.produced_artist = "17"
```

**Problem**

As an album has many tracks, my result will show a couple of time the same album. In order to make a discography, I'd like to have all the albums from an artist.
Is there a way to do that in MySQL ?

Comment: `GROUP BY album_id`? Note: This will 'kill' all following results and only display the album once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use  `SELECT DISTINCT` as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT album_name 
FROM albums AS a, 
 tracks AS t, 
 produced AS p 
WHERE p.produced_track = t.track_id 
AND t.track_album = a.album_id 
AND p.produced_artist = "17"
```

This should do it...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of retrieving too many rows and removing duplicates you can also use a sub-query

```
SELECT album_name 
FROM albums AS a
WHERE album_id IN (SELECT t.track_album
                   FROM tracks t
                      JOIN produced AS p ON p.produced_track = t.track_id 
                   WHERE p.produced_artist = 17)
```

You should also get used to using explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of the implicit joins hidden in the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 1):

You should try:  `SELECT DISTINCT album_name 
FROM albums AS a, 
     tracks AS t, 
     produced AS p 
WHERE p.produced_track = t.track_id 
  AND t.track_album = a.album_id 
AND p.produced_artist = "17"`